# How to send a request when push notification is cancelled in Android

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

When an application receives `push notification` from `FCM`, it calls `onMessageReceived`. (See [1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273699/how-to-stack-firebase-cloud-messaging-notifications-when-the-application-is-not) or [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242446/fcm-push-notification-not-received-when-app-is-killed-swiped-out).)

When a user *taps the notification*, it launches the applications, then it sends a request to a server that the user has read the notification.

I want to know when a device received a push notification, but *the user swiped it* (or cleared all notifications). I want to *send a request to the server* that the user simply *cancelled the notification*.

I tried to send `BroadcastReceiver` and show logs (see [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465849/how-to-use-notification-deleteintent) or [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671453/catch-on-swipe-to-dismiss-event)), but it works when the application *was opened when the notification delivered*. I suppose, that

MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    ...
    // An event when a user swipes a notification.
    val intent = Intent(this, NotificationBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
    intent.action = "notification_cancelled"
    val deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
    notificationBuilder.setDeleteIntent(deleteIntent)

    // Navigation to an activity when a user taps the notification.
    // It doesn't matter to this question.
    val intent2 = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val navigateIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationId, intent2,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(navigateIntent)
    ...
}
```

NotificationBroadcastReceiver:

```
class NotificationBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Timber.d("NotificationBroadcastReceiver onReceive")
        Toast.makeText(context, "Notification dismissed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        // Send a request to the server.
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.uremont.NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".receiver.NotificationBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="notification_cancelled" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

works only when the application is opened. But when the application is in background or killed, it doesn't react to swipe. Probably we shouldn't use `BroadcastReceiver`, for instance, use `PendingIntent.getService` or `PendingIntent.getForegroundService`.

Can we send a request to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a short time it worked right (though I hardly changed much). After a lot of research I made this solution. Tested on several Android emulators and devices from API 19 to API 30.

Because using `BroadcastReceiver` is [not safe](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/topic/android-hacking-security-part-3-exploiting-broadcast-receivers/), add in AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".NotificationBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false"
    />
```

NotificationBroadcastReceiver:

```
class NotificationBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Timber.d("NotificationBroadcastReceiver onReceive")

        if (intent.extras != null) {
            // Receive parameters of a cancelled notification.
            val authToken = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TOKEN)
            val code = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_CODE)
            Timber.d("token = $authToken, code = $code")
            // We can access context even if the application was removed from the recent list.
            Toast.makeText(context, "Notification $code was cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            // Send data to a server.
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val EXTRA_TOKEN = "EXTRA_TOKEN"
        const val EXTRA_CODE = "EXTRA_CODE"
    }
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    ...
    // Get notification code from data.
    val code = remoteMessage.data["code"]

    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
    ...

    val notificationId = Random.nextInt()
    val intent = Intent(this, NotificationBroadcastReceiver::class.java).apply {
        putExtra(EXTRA_TOKEN, authToken)
        putExtra(EXTRA_CODE, code)
    }
    val deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, notificationId, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
    notificationBuilder.setDeleteIntent(deleteIntent)

    val notification = notificationBuilder.build()
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
}
```

Send a push message to Android device with it's push token, for instance:

```
{
  "to": "ddSOGiz4QzmY.....:APA91bHgoincFw.......",
  "data": {
    "title": "Test",
    "message": "Test",
    "code": "ABCDEF"
  }
}
```

You can see different schemes of delivering push messages [here](https://github.com/shahzadafridi/FCM-Notification-Test-Cases). If a user presses "Force stop" at the application, it [won't receive](https://support.learnyst.com/en/articles/1151726-why-push-notification-are-not-received-by-learners) push messages (except "AliExpress", ha-ha).

When the user dismisses push notification, `NotificationBroadcastReceiver::onReceive()` is called. An application gets parameters of the push message. Then we can see a toast message and send these parameters to the server.

When the user presses "Clear all" notifications, all dismiss events are fired. So, you will see a sequence of toasts. The server will receive several requests simultaneously (check that it can handle, for instance, 10 requests in 0.01 second).